# Is module loading in Nodejs deterministic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, require, circular-dependency

I'm trying to debug some Node.js code where there are several circular dependencies. It smells like an issue with modules being partially loaded due to the circular dependencies (the errors are all of the form `x is not a function`). However, the errors only show up very infrequently, and when they do show up, happen at different parts of the code. So I'm unable to reproduce the errors in any deterministic way.

This leads to me to believe that the module loading order is **not** deterministic, which contradicts some existing material I've read (e.g. [this article](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de)). Is that's the case, the problems I'm seeing would make much more sense.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to remove the circular dependencies. It's a recipe for ongoing headaches and the sooner you make the refactor, the sooner you can breathe easy. This link has some good advice on the topic: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/

Comment: Yes, I'm in complete agreement that circular dependencies should be avoided. The code base is quite complex though, and it would take a very long time to clean that up. The main cause of confusion is that from what I've read, module loading should be deterministic even if there are circular dependencies, but I am unable to consistently reproduce the errors I'm seeing.